# swap values between two String values in minimum iterations

Tags: java, swap

I have :

```
String a1 = "Hello";
String a2 = "World";
```

I want `a2 becomes a1` and `a1 becomes a2` i.e. they interchange values.

Doing to without writing a function:

```
a1 = "World";
a2 = "Hello";
```

want to write a function that can do it in minimum number of iterations.

Comment: No iterations are required at all. You simply don't need a loop for this. Do you mean *instructions*?

Comment: store `a1` in `tmp`. Assign `a1 = a2`. Assign `a2 = tmp`. This is standard [`swap` operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_(computer_science)#Using_a_temporary_variable).

Comment: Why @Amila cant see what I have tried? Why Boris cant write solution in Answers box? Why Andy dont understand that meaning of itrations? Why downvoters do not care to comment?

Comment: Because this was a "gimme teh codes" question which showed no effort on your part. These "help vampire" questions offend some people here, others find them a perfect vehicle for gaining cheap rep. In the end no one, especially you, is bettered by people doing trivial work for you. Have a happy day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `String` is immutable in Java,
you cannot change the value of `a1` and `a2`,
and the question is quite confusing.

What you can do is swap the variables:

```
String tmp = a1;
a1 = a2;
a2 = tmp;
```

But I suspect this is an exercise, and perhaps it was intended more like this:

> Given `char[] a1 = {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}` and `char[] a2 = ...`, swap their values in the minimum number of steps without reassigning these variables.

Then you would iterate over the elements of the arrays,
and perform swapping character by character just like I did earlier with the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
x = new String[] { y, y = x }[0];
```

I tested it, and it's just as fast as the other method. Take a look:

```
data <- read.csv("~swapVars.csv")

dim(data)[1] #Size of dataset
# [1] 3799582

head(data) # Preview of data (Nano Seconds)
#    oldWay newWay
# 1     75     75
# 2     82     83
# 3     67     67
# 4     75     67
# 5     98     60
# 6     75     75

summary(data)
# oldWay             newWay       
# Min.   :      52   Min.   :     52  
# 1st Qu.:      60   1st Qu.:     60  
# Median :      60   Median :     60  
# Mean   :      84   Mean   :     78  
# 3rd Qu.:      67   3rd Qu.:     67  
# Max.   :16032716   Max.   :8381087  

t.test(data$oldWay, data$newWay)

# Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  data$oldWay and data$newWay
# t = 0.7796, df = 7237880, p-value = 0.4356
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#   -9.516198 22.087260
# sample estimates:
#   mean of x mean of y 
# 83.96287  77.67734
```

So what this means is, I tested both methods 3,799,582 times with random placement and random text to eliminate third variables. I then did a t-test on the two datasets and found no significant difference between my way or with the old way, regarding latency of time (Nano Seconds).

The times do vary, but it's safe to say that not only is my method shorter, but is also just as fast as the old way.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a solution:

```
a1 +=  a2;      
a2 = a1.replaceFirst(a2 + "$", "");
a1 = a1.replaceFirst("^" + a2, "");
```